# Is there a way to hyperlink an image that needs a <p tag to sit right inside footer?

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

```
<p style="text-align: center">
  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-759 aligncenter" /><img
    src="https://steamboateramuseum.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/ViFLverttransparent.gif"
  />
</p>
```

This is what I have now, I have been asked to link it but every time I add my <a tag and url to hyperlink it just doesn't work! Where would I fit a hyperlink into this? I am sorry for the stupid question in advance.

Comment: I don't see your code.

Comment: @elizabethptp So where are you adding <a>?

Comment: I am sorry it keeps saying my reputation is not high enough to post it:

I have been trying to add <a around the <img but within the <p and it just isn't working 

this is the jist:
<p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-759 aligncenter" /><img src="https://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg" /></p>

Comment: So if you want an image to be a link, your <a> tag needs to go between the <p> and <img> tag.

Comment: <p><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="some image"/></a></p>

Answer (score 1):

Okay so based on your comments I think I have understood your problem. Do following ->

```
    <p style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="here goes your link e.g. https://google.com">
          <img src="i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg" />
        </a>
    </p>
```

Depending on your usecase you might have to update style to show it in better way, but this will work functionally

Comment: Thank you!! this is the answer, I can't upvote you but this solves it!!

Answer (score 0):

Although you question wasn't clear, but what i understood is your hyperlink containing an image is not working. Maybe you're missing Something in your quotes? anyway here is an example of a working hyperlink with an image.

```
<a href="yourURL.com"><img src="images/someimage.jpg" title="Image hyper link" width="300" height="200" /></a>
```

Comment: So I don't know why it doesn't show the code I included in my question and it's horrible cobbled code. I have attempted using that answer from another post on here, but because of how the image needs to sit within the footer widget, it seems like has to be enclosed in a <p, this horrid thing is the only way I've gotten it even in the remotely correct location:
<p style="text-align: center;"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-759 aligncenter" /><img src="https://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg" /></p>

Comment: Try this, but are you sure your class(es) Inside the class attribute exist?  
<p><a href="yourURL.com"><img  class="classhere" src="i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg" title="Image hyper link" width="300" height="200" /></a></p>